# SNMP implementation

Tags: snmp

Have to work on the snmp implementation to check the status of the different parameters of a device. Am new to this and kinda confused with the steps. How do I function with the mib's and is there any need of xml parsing?

Comment: You might start from an existing SNMP library of the programming language you use. That should make you able to write a real question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there is no need for XML parsing. The steps depend on whether you are writing an SNMP agent or an SNMP manager and what SNMP framework you are using, assuming you're not writing everything from scratch.

Assuming you are working on the agent, the steps are usually these:

1. If you are creating a new MIB, you need to create the text file that defines the objects in the MIB, see http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Writing_your_own_MIBs as a starting point
2. Once you have a MIB (either one that you wrote in step 1, or an existing MIB you downloaded), you use a MIB compiler to generate code from that MIB
3. The generated code will typically contain stub functions that you need to fill in for getting and setting MIB object values

See http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorials for information on how to implement a MIB for the net-snmp agent code base.

Comment: Would be good to know whether you're implementing things on the manager or agent side, what framework and language you're using